# Postgres configuration for better performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.2

We have done a PostreSql database Based ERP project. I have 32 GB RAM Windows Server 2012 R2 system. Out of 32 GB, I have used 8 GB for JVM and assuming 4 GB for OS, I have tried to tune the postgres with 20 GB RAM.
I have find out the configuration from the below link:
https://www.pgconfig.org/#/tuning?total_ram=20&max_connections=300&environment_name=OLTP&pg_version=9.2&os_type=Windows&arch=x86-64&share_link=true

But the performance goes down after the change. What could be the reason. As I am less knowledge in the postgres server maintenance, if anything more required for you to assess/answer let me know.

**UPDATE**
shared_buffers (integer) : 512 MB
effective_cache_size (integer) : 15 GB
work_mem (integer): 68 MB
maintenance_work_mem (integer): 1 GB

checkpoint_segments (integer): 96
checkpoint_completion_target (floating): 0.9
 wal_buffers (integer): 16 MB

Comment: Update your answer with your changes on postgresql.conf. You set to 20GB on what parameter? Anyway, AFAIK PostgreSQL on Windows cannot use more than 512MB (`shared_buffers`).

Comment: @michel.milezzi Thanks. I have updated the question. Please find the changes in the UPDATE

Comment: I recommended to start from from [pgTune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/) suggested config